# QGIS 3.28.5 problems opening SQLite DB

Tags: qgis, python, error, database, sqlite

I´m unable to open my Database and have no clue about the problem. I have the following Python error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 456, in rowCount
              self._refreshIndex(parent, True)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 505, in _refreshIndex
              if item.populate():
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 198, in populate
              tables = database.tables()
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\plugin.py", line 572, in tables
              tables = self.connector.getTables(schema.name if schema else None, sys_tables)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\spatialite\connector.py", line 177, in getTables
              vectors = self.getVectorTables(schema)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\spatialite\connector.py", line 271, in getVectorTables
              for tbl in c.fetchall():
             sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'name' with text 'a380_brutv��gelreviere'
```

the last layer was completely empty.

Can I use this database again?

Comment: I believe that the SpatiaLite database is created somehow wrong. In SpatiaLite the texts should use UTF-8 and if native data is using some other encoding the texts should be converted during import https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users/c/-lugZZxQg6k. If you just need the data a workaround could be to update  'a380_brutv��gelreviere' into  'a380_brut__gelreviere'. If that is a table name renaming may be complicated because of foreign keys and triggers.